# Constructing fractions Interview challenge

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I recently came across the following interview question, I was wondering if a dynamic programming approach would work, or/and if there was some kind of mathematical insight that would make the solution easier... Its very similar to how ieee754 doubles are constructed.

**Question:**
There is vector V of N double values. Where the value at the ith index of the vector is equal to 1/2^(i+1). eg: 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16 etc...

You're to write a function that takes one double 'r' as input, where 0 < r < 1, and output the indexes of V to stdout that when summed will give a value closest to the value 'r' than any other combination of indexes from the vector V.

Furthermore the number of indexes should be a minimum, and in the event there are two solutions, the solution closest to zero should be preferred.

```
void getIndexes(std::vector<double>& V, double r)
{
 .... 
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<double> V;
   // populate V...
   double r = 0.3;
   getIndexes(V,r);
   return 0;
}
```

**Note:** It seems like there are a few SO'ers that aren't in the mood of reading the question completely. So lets all note the following:

1. The solution, aka the sum may be larger than r - hence any strategy incrementally subtracting fractions from r, until it hits zero or near zero is wrong
2. There are examples of r, where there will be 2 solutions, that is |r-s0| == |r-s1| and s0 < s1 - in this case s0 should be selected, this makes the problem slightly more difficult, as the knapsack style solutions tend to greedy overestimates first.
3. If you believe this problem is trivial, you most likely haven't understood it. Hence it would be a good idea to read the question again.

**EDIT (Matthieu M.):** 2 examples for `V = {1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32}`

- `r = 0.3`, `S = {1, 3}`
- `r = 0.256652`, `S = {1}`

Comment: Note that the general case of this problem (The vector is not `2^-(i+1)`, but arbitrary values) is NP-Hard, since it is a variation of the subset sum problem. However, with the `2^-(i+1)` restriction, I believe the problem can be solved efficiently.

Comment: @amit: Actually, I think this is a simplified version of the knapsack problem.

Comment: Subset sum problem is Knapsack with `weight=value` for each item, so we are both correct :). Note that though subset sum is looking for a subset with value 0, it is easy to make the problems identical by adding an item of size `-W`, where `W` is the size of the bag.

Comment: @amit: now that i think about it, that is correct - very true, we're both right. :D

Comment: @XanderTulip: Do you think that we have to care about the finite representation of a `double` ?

Comment: @MatthieuM: I supposed for the sake of simplicity, that double precision errors could be ignored, essentially one could assume that the sum is correct - which in theory it should be since were adding recpricols of powers of 2, which are single bit representations - but i digress :)

Comment: @XanderTulip: With regards to your edit - on further consideration you are correct, and this problem may not admit a greedy solution. People may find this easier to understand if you add concrete examples to your question (say, the optimal representation of `0.6` as a sum of fractions.) *{Further note: you may not have intended it, but your remark "It seems like there are some SO'ers who are not in the mood of reading the question completely..." sounds a little abrasive. Correcting misconceptions is fine, but do it politely.}*

Comment: Show me an example of V and r and the solution set.

Comment: @kasavbere: I added two examples, that are hopefully right. Xander please check them out and correct them/remove them if necessary.

Comment: An example would be representing `0.70` as a sum of the numbers in the set `{0.500, 0.250, 0.125}`. A greedy algorithm (as in my deleted answer) gives `0.500 + 0.125 = 0.625`, which has an error of `0.075`. A better solution is `0.500 + 0.250 = 0.750`, which has an error of `0.050`.

Comment: This is an idiotic interview question, because of it's difficulty, unless people have access to a compiler, which they usually don't at the interview.

Comment: All: I don't believe this problem requires dynamic programming at all. Instead, it can be reduced to the problem of encoding an integer in binary, and solved in `O(n)` time. See my new answer below (with proof and example code.)

Comment: @VJovic: Actually, I found it so simple (no dynamic programming or anything), that I wonder if I missed the point...

Comment: @MatthieuM. You did it in a very nice way, but could you do it without a compiler?

Comment: @VJovic: The interview question would either be phrased as "think about what approach you would use to solve...", which is asking for the algorithm (not compilable code), or "here's a whiteboard, have a crack at writing C++", which is asking if you know enough C++ syntax to have a *decent shot* at writing code without a compiler.

Comment: @VJovic: I think the "with some debug output" in my answer clearly shows that it did not work at first ;) I of course had to fix the solution a bit to make it compile, and then prune a bug or two before it produced the right answer.

Answer (score 12):

## Algorithm

Consider a target number `r` and a set `F` of fractions `{1/2, 1/4, ... 1/(2^N)}`. Let the smallest fraction, `1/(2^N)`, be denoted `P`.

Then the optimal sum will be equal to:

```
S = P * round(r/P)
```

That is, the optimal sum `S` will be some **integer** multiple of the smallest fraction available, `P`. The maximum error, `err = r - S`, is `± 1/2 * 1/(2^N)`. No better solution is possible because this would require the use of a number smaller than `1/(2^N)`, which is the smallest number in the set `F`.

Since the fractions `F` are all power-of-two multiples of `P = 1/(2^N)`, *any* integer multiple of `P` can be expressed as a sum of the fractions in `F`. To obtain the list of fractions that should be used, encode the integer `round(r/P)` in binary and read off `1` in the `kth` binary place as "include the `kth` fraction in the solution".

## Example:

> Take `r = 0.3` and `F` as `{1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, 1/32}`.

1. Multiply the entire problem by 32.

   > Take `r = 9.6`, and `F` as `{16, 8, 4, 2, 1}`.
2. Round `r` to the nearest integer.

   > Take `r = 10`.
3. Encode `10` as a binary integer (five places)

   ```
   10 = 0b 0 1 0 1 0    ( 8 + 2 )
           ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
           | | | | |
           | | | | 1
           | | | 2
           | | 4
           | 8
           16
   ```
4. Associate each binary bit with a fraction.

   ```
      = 0b 0 1 0 1 0    ( 1/4 + 1/16 = 0.3125 )
           ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
           | | | | |
           | | | | 1/32
           | | | 1/16
           | | 1/8
           | 1/4
           1/2
   ```

## Proof

Consider transforming the problem by multiplying all the numbers involved by `2**N` so that all the fractions become integers.

The original problem:

> Consider a target number `r` in the range `0 < r < 1`, and a list of fractions `{1/2, 1/4, .... 1/(2**N)`. Find the subset of the list of fractions that sums to `S` such that `error = r - S` is minimised.

Becomes the following equivalent problem (after multiplying by `2**N`):

> Consider a target number `r` in the range `0 < r < 2**N` and a list of **integers** `{2**(N-1), 2**(N-2), ... , 4, 2, 1}`. Find the subset of the list of integers that sums to `S` such that `error = r - S` is minimised.

Choosing powers of two that sum to a given number (with as little error as possible) is simply binary encoding of an integer. This problem therefore reduces to binary encoding of a integer.

- Existence of solution: Any positive floating point number `r`, `0 < r < 2**N`, can be cast to an integer and represented in binary form.
- Optimality: The maximum error in the integer version of the solution is the round-off error of `±0.5`. (In the original problem, the maximum error is `±0.5 * 1/2**N`.)
- Uniqueness: for any positive (floating point) number there is a unique integer representation and therefore a unique binary representation. (Possible exception of `0.5` = see below.)

## Implementation (Python)

This function converts the problem to the integer equivalent, rounds off `r` to an integer, then reads off the binary representation of `r` as an integer to get the required fractions.

```
def conv_frac (r,N):
    # Convert to equivalent integer problem.
    R = r * 2**N
    S = int(round(R))

    # Convert integer S to N-bit binary representation (i.e. a character string
    # of 1's and 0's.) Note use of [2:] to trim leading '0b' and zfill() to
    # zero-pad to required length.
    bin_S = bin(S)[2:].zfill(N)

    nums = list()
    for index, bit in enumerate(bin_S):
        k = index + 1
        if bit == '1':
            print "%i : 1/%i or %f" % (index, 2**k, 1.0/(2**k))
            nums.append(1.0/(2**k))
    S = sum(nums)
    e = r - S

    print """
    Original number        `r` : %f
    Number of fractions    `N` : %i (smallest fraction 1/%i)
    Sum of fractions       `S` : %f
    Error                  `e` : %f
    """ % (r,N,2**N,S,e)
```

Sample output:

```
>>> conv_frac(0.3141,10)
1 : 1/4 or 0.250000
3 : 1/16 or 0.062500
8 : 1/512 or 0.001953

    Original number        `r` : 0.314100
    Number of fractions    `N` : 10 (smallest fraction 1/1024)
    Sum of fractions       `S` : 0.314453
    Error                  `e` : -0.000353

>>> conv_frac(0.30,5)
1 : 1/4 or 0.250000
3 : 1/16 or 0.062500

    Original number        `r` : 0.300000
    Number of fractions    `N` : 5 (smallest fraction 1/32)
    Sum of fractions       `S` : 0.312500
    Error                  `e` : -0.012500
```

## Addendum: the `0.5` problem

If `r * 2**N` ends in `0.5`, then it could be rounded up or down. That is, there are two possible representations as a sum-of-fractions.

If, as in the original problem statement, you want the representation that uses fewest fractions (i.e. the least number of `1` bits in the binary representation), just try both rounding options and pick whichever one is more economical.

Comment: I'd really like to know why this was downvoted when it finds a solution that appears to be correct as far as I can see.

Comment: @MatthieuM. : To be fair, I posted a quick and dirty answer at first and edited it into the detailed post you see here. I think the downvote was from an earlier version.

Comment: I guess that it one more reasons for downvoters to leave a note: so they can be notified when an edit is made... On the other hand, even though it's correct, it's quite a long-winded solution.

Comment: @MatthieuM. : I wanted to cover all my bases. When you get right down to it, my original thought was more like Marwin's very quick and dirty solution (explicitly read the bit patterns in the floating-point representation of `r`) but I didn't have the gumption to write that. ;)

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps I am dumb...

The only trick I can see here is that the sum of `(1/2)^(i+1)` for `i` in `[0..n)` where `n` tends towards infinity gives `1`. This simple fact proves that `(1/2)^i` is always superior to `sum (1/2)^j` for `j` in `[i+1, n)`, whatever `n` is.

So, when looking for our indices, it does not seem we have much choice. Let's start with `i = 0`

- either `r` is superior to `2^-(i+1)` and thus we *need* it
- or it is inferior and we need to choose whether `2^-(i+1)` OR `sum 2^-j` for `j` in `[i+2, N]` is closest (deferring to the latter in case of equality)

The only step that could be costly is obtaining the sum, but it can be precomputed once and for all (and even precomputed lazily).

```
// The resulting vector contains at index i the sum of 2^-j for j in [i+1, N]
// and is padded with one 0 to get the same length as `v`
static std::vector<double> partialSums(std::vector<double> const& v) {
    std::vector<double> result;

    // When summing doubles, we need to start with the smaller ones
    // because of the precision of representations...

    double sum = 0;
    BOOST_REVERSE_FOREACH(double d, v) {
        sum += d;
        result.push_back(sum);
    }

    result.pop_back(); // there is a +1 offset in the indexes of the result

    std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());

    result.push_back(0); // pad the vector to have the same length as `v`

    return result;   
}

// The resulting vector contains the indexes elected
static std::vector<size_t> getIndexesImpl(std::vector<double> const& v,
                                          std::vector<double> const& ps,
                                          double r)
{
  std::vector<size_t> indexes;

  for (size_t i = 0, max = v.size(); i != max; ++i) {
      if (r >= v[i]) {
          r -= v[i];
          indexes.push_back(i);
          continue;
      }

      // We favor the closest to 0 in case of equality
      // which is the sum of the tail as per the theorem above.
      if (std::fabs(r - v[i]) < std::fabs(r - ps[i])) {
          indexes.push_back(i);
          return indexes;
      }
  }

  return indexes;
}

std::vector<size_t> getIndexes(std::vector<double>& v, double r) {
    std::vector<double> const ps = partialSums(v);
    return getIndexesImpl(v, ps, r);
}
```

The code runs (with some debug output) at [ideone](http://ideone.com/y7RWz). Note that for `0.3` it gives:

```
0.3:
   1: 0.25
   3: 0.0625
=> 0.3125
```

which is slightly different from the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

At the risk of downvotes, this problem seems to be rather straightforward.  Just start with the largest and smallest numbers you can produce out of `V`, adjust each index in turn until you have the two possible closest answers.  Then evaluate which one is the better answer.

Here is untested code (in a language that I don't write):

```
void getIndexes(std::vector<double>& V, double r)
{
  double v_lower = 0;
  double v_upper = 1.0 - 0.5**V.size();
  std::vector<int> index_lower;
  std::vector<int> index_upper;

  if (v_upper <= r)
  {
    // The answer is trivial.
    for (int i = 0; i < V.size(); i++)
      cout << i;
    return;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
    if (v_lower + V[i] <= r)
    {
      v_lower += V[i];
      index_lower.push_back(i);
    }

    if (r <= v_upper - V[i])
      v_upper -= V[i];
    else
      index_upper.push_back(i);
  }

  if (r - v_lower < v_upper - r)
    printIndexes(index_lower);
  else if (v_upper - r < r - v_lower)
    printIndexes(index_upper);
  else if (v_upper.size() < v_lower.size())
    printIndexes(index_upper);
  else
    printIndexes(index_lower);
}

void printIndexes(std::vector<int>& ind)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < ind.size(); i++)
  {
    cout << ind[i];
  }
}
```

Did I get the job! :D

(Please note, this is horrible code that relies on our knowing **exactly** what V has in it...)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you have test cases, try the code below. It is a dynamic-programming approach.

```
1] exp: given 1/2^i, find the largest i as exp. Eg. 1/32 returns 5.
2] max: 10^exp where exp=i.
3] create an array of size max+1 to hold all possible sums of the elements of V.
   Actually the array holds the indexes, since that's what you want.
4] dynamically compute the sums (all invalids remain null)
5] the last while loop finds the nearest correct answer.
```

Here is the code:

```
public class Subset {

public static List<Integer> subsetSum(double[] V, double r) {
    int exp = exponent(V);
    int max = (int) Math.pow(10, exp);
    //list to hold all possible sums of the elements in V
    List<Integer> indexes[] = new ArrayList[max + 1];
    indexes[0] = new ArrayList();//base case
    //dynamically compute the sums
    for (int x=0; x<V.length; x++) {
        int u = (int) (max*V[x]);
        for(int i=max; i>=u; i--) if(null != indexes[i-u]) {
            List<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<Integer>(indexes[i - u]);
            tmp.add(x);
            indexes[i] = tmp;
        }
    }
   //find the best answer
    int i = (int)(max*r);
    int j=i;
    while(null == indexes[i] && null == indexes[j]) {
        i--;j++;
    }
      return indexes[i]==null || indexes[i].isEmpty()?indexes[j]:indexes[i];
}// subsetSum

private static int exponent(double[] V) {
    double d = V[V.length-1];
    int i = (int) (1/d);
    String s = Integer.toString(i,2);
    return s.length()-1;
}// summation

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] V = {1/2.,1/4.,1/8.,1/16.,1/32.};
    double r = 0.6, s=0.3,t=0.256652;
    System.out.println(subsetSum(V,r));//[0, 3, 4]
    System.out.println(subsetSum(V,s));//[1, 3]
    System.out.println(subsetSum(V,t));//[1]
}
}// class
```

Here are results of running the code:

```
For 0.600000  get 0.593750 => [0, 3, 4]
For 0.300000  get 0.312500 => [1, 3]
For 0.256652  get 0.250000 => [1]
For 0.700000  get 0.687500 => [0, 2, 3]
For 0.710000  get 0.718750 => [0, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Interestingly, we do not find the same answer for `0.3` (I find `{1, 3} = 0.3125 (+0.0125)` you find `{1, 4} = 0.28125 (-0.01875)`). Is this a typo or does your code never approximate from above ?

Comment: Try running the code. I provide some additional test results.

Comment: It was a typo then :) As for running, I don't know which strange language it's written in, but it seems way to verbose for me to bother anyway.

Comment: So you don't recognize `Java`, the staple of object-oriented programming; you find my algorithm verbose although it has fewer lines than yours (unless you somehow lump in the test segments and the explanations I provide); and you don't seem to know how (i.e. bother) to read codes you didn't write. The algorithm is simple: 1] create an Array to hold the results; 2] dynamically compute each sum (as fast as it gets); 3] find the sum closest to `r`. In subset-sum studies, this is the partition approach, and it's very accurate.

Comment: Actually, I was making a pun on Java's verbosity and... my lack of enthusiasm for the language. I was reacting to your "try running the code": I cannot, I don't have a Java compiler, and I don't plan on having one if I can help it. I did not comment on the algorithm it seems to work which is great, however I am not too savvy on algorithms, so I can't eyeball its complexity. Finally... it's not a code golf ;)

Answer (score 2):

I will start by saying that I do believe that this problem is trivial...

*(waits until all stones have been thrown)*

Yes, I did read the OP's edit that says that I have to re-read the question if I think so. Therefore I might be missing something that I fail to see - in this case please excuse my ignorance and feel free to point out my mistakes.

I don't see this as a dynamic programming problem. At the risk of sounding naive, why not try keeping two estimations of `r` while searching for indices - namely an under-estimation and an over-estimation. After all, if `r` does not equal any sum that can be computed from elements of `V`, it will lie between some two sums of the kind. Our goal is to find these sums and to report which is closer to `r`.

I threw together some quick-and-dirty Python code that does the job. The answer it reports is correct for the two test cases that the OP provided. Note that if the `return` is structured such that at least one index always has to be returned - even if the best estimation is no indices at all.

```
def estimate(V, r):
  lb = 0               # under-estimation (lower-bound)
  lbList = []
  ub = 1 - 0.5**len(V) # over-estimation = sum of all elements of V
  ubList = range(len(V))

  # calculate closest under-estimation and over-estimation
  for i in range(len(V)):
    if r == lb + V[i]:
      return (lbList + [i], lb + V[i])
    elif r == ub:
      return (ubList, ub)
    elif r > lb + V[i]:
      lb += V[i]
      lbList += [i]
    elif lb + V[i] < ub:
      ub = lb + V[i]
      ubList = lbList + [i]
  return (ubList, ub) if ub - r < r - lb else (lbList, lb) if lb != 0 else ([len(V) - 1], V[len(V) - 1])

# populate V
N = 5 # number of elements
V = []
for i in range(1, N + 1):
  V += [0.5**i]

# test
r = 0.484375 # this value is equidistant from both under- and over-estimation
print "r:", r
estimate = estimate(V, r)
print "Indices:", estimate[0]
print "Estimate:", estimate[1]
```

Note: after finishing writing my answer I noticed that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10482271/914790) follows the same logic. Alas!

Comment: I think the only case in which you might need the "estimate from above" is when the optimal solution differs in the least-significant bit (that is, the number should have been "rounded up" instead of "rounded down".) You could probably get away with doing just one pass of the greedy algorithm ("from below") and then manually check if a "slightly larger" solution gives a closer result.

Comment: @Li-aungYip As I mentioned, this is just some quick code that I threw together. It could be optimized in several ways. But it still does only one pass over the `V` array (or is this not what you mean by "one pass of the greedy algorithm"?).

Answer (score 1):

The solution implements [Polynomial time approximate algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Polynomial_time_approximate_algorithm). Output of the program is the same as outputs of another solutions.

```
#include <math.h>                                                                                                                                             
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                            
#include <vector>                                                                                                                                             
#include <algorithm>                                                                                                                                          
#include <functional>                                                                                                                                         

void populate(std::vector<double> &vec, int count)                                                                                                            
{                                                                                                                                                             
    double val = .5;                                                                                                                                          
    vec.clear();                                                                                                                                              
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {                                                                                                                         
        vec.push_back(val);                                                                                                                                   
        val *= .5;                                                                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                                                         
}                                                                                                                                                             

void remove_values_with_large_error(const std::vector<double> &vec, std::vector<double> &res, double r, double max_error)                                     
{                                                                                                                                                             
    std::vector<double>::const_iterator iter;                                                                                                                 
    double min_err, err;                                                                                                                                      

    min_err = 1.0;                                                                                                                                            
    for (iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter) {                                                                                                     
        err = fabs(*iter - r);                                                                                                                                
        if (err < max_error) {                                                                                                                                
            res.push_back(*iter);                                                                                                                             
        }                                                                                                                                                     
        min_err = std::min(err, min_err);                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                         
}

void find_partial_sums(const std::vector<double> &vec, std::vector<double> &res, double r)                                                                    
{                                                                                                                                                             
    std::vector<double> svec, tvec, uvec;                                                                                                                     
    std::vector<double>::const_iterator iter;                                                                                                                 
    int step = 0;                                                                                                                                             

    svec.push_back(0.);                                                                                                                                       
    for (iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter) {                                                                                                     
        step++;                                                                                                                                               
        printf("step %d, svec.size() %d\n", step, svec.size());                                                                                               
        tvec.clear();                                                                                                                                         
        std::transform(svec.begin(), svec.end(), back_inserter(tvec),                                                                                         
                       std::bind2nd(std::plus<double>(), *iter));                                                                                             
        uvec.clear();                                                                                                                                         
        uvec.insert(uvec.end(), svec.begin(), svec.end());                                                                                                    
        uvec.insert(uvec.end(), tvec.begin(), tvec.end());                                                                                                    
        sort(uvec.begin(), uvec.end());                                                                                                                       
        uvec.erase(unique(uvec.begin(), uvec.end()), uvec.end());                                                                                             

        svec.clear();                                                                                                                                         
        remove_values_with_large_error(uvec, svec, r, *iter * 4);                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                                                         

    sort(svec.begin(), svec.end());                                                                                                                           
    svec.erase(unique(svec.begin(), svec.end()), svec.end());                                                                                                 

    res.clear();                                                                                                                                              
    res.insert(res.end(), svec.begin(), svec.end());                                                                                                          
} 

double find_closest_value(const std::vector<double> &sums, double r)                                                                                          
{                                                                                                                                                             
    std::vector<double>::const_iterator iter;                                                                                                                 
    double min_err, res, err;                                                                                                                                 

    min_err = fabs(sums.front() - r);                                                                                                                         
    res = sums.front();                                                                                                                                       

    for (iter = sums.begin(); iter != sums.end(); ++iter) {                                                                                                   
        err = fabs(*iter - r);                                                                                                                                
        if (err < min_err) {                                                                                                                                  
            min_err = err;                                                                                                                                    
            res = *iter;                                                                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                         
    printf("found value %lf with err %lf\n", res, min_err);                                                                                                   
    return res;                                                                                                                                               
}                                                                                                                                                             

void print_indexes(const std::vector<double> &vec, double value)                                                                                              
{                                                                                                                                                             
    std::vector<double>::const_iterator iter;                                                                                                                 
    int index = 0;                                                                                                                                            

    printf("indexes: [");                                                                                                                                     
    for (iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter, ++index) {                                                                                            
        if (value >= *iter) {                                                                                                                                  
            printf("%d, ", index);                                                                                                                            
            value -= *iter;                                                                                                                                   
        }                                                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                         
    printf("]\n");                                                                                                                                            
}                                                                                                                                                             

int main(int argc, char **argv)                                                                                                                               
{                                                                                                                                                             
    std::vector<double> vec, sums;                                                                                                                            
    double r = .7;                                                                                                                                            
    int n = 5;                                                                                                                                                
    double value;                                                                                                                                             
    populate(vec, n);                                                                                                                                         
    find_partial_sums(vec, sums, r);                                                                                                                          
    value = find_closest_value(sums, r);                                                                                                                      
    print_indexes(vec, value);                                                                                                                                
    return 0;                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the vector and search for the closest fraction available to r. store that index, subtract the value from  r, and repeat with the remainder of r. iterate until r is reached, or no such index can be found.

Example :

0.3 - the biggest value available would be 0.25. (index 2). the remainder now is 0.05

0.05 - the biggest value available would be 0.03125 - the remainder will be 0.01875

etc.

etc. every step would be an O(logN) search in a sorted array. the number of steps will also be O(logN) total complexity will be than O(logN^2).

Comment: there will situations where the real solution will be larger than r, your proposal does not take those solutions into account. The example of when r = 0.3 and N is 30 is an example of such a situation. btw I didn't -1, but i wont be accepting your answer.

Comment: oh closest can be greater as well. Can be adjusted easily.

Comment: Read the question properly, for example N = 11, r = 0.3, the solution is: 1/4,1/32,1/64,1/512,1/1024,1/2048, your suggestion doesn't work, don't assume something that you know which is similar can be applied here, this isn't a simple bisection problem.

Comment: @WeaselFox: why do you sort the `vector` ? Your method looks like a division of some kind. Start with n = 0, if `(1/2)^n` is inferior to the target, store `n`, remove `(1/2)^n` from the amound, increment `n`, continue... I don't see where the "sort" steps comes from.

Comment: @XanderTulip For N = 11, r = 0.3, the solution does not include 1/2048. The error if it's included is 0.00029296875, otherwise it's 0.0001953125.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not dynamic programming question**

**The output should rather be vector of ints (indexes), not vector of doubles**

This might by off 0-2 in exact values, this is just concept:

A) output zero index until the r0 (r - index values already outputded) is bigger than 1/2

B) Inspect the internal representation of r0 double and:

x (1st bit shift) = -Exponent;  // The bigger exponent, the smallest numbers (bigger x in 1/2^(x) you begin with)

Inspect bit representation of the fraction part of float in cycle with body:
(direction depends on little/big endian)

```
{
  if (bit is 1)
    output index x;
  x++;
```

}

Complexity of each step is constant, so overall it is O(n) where n is size of output.

Comment: Offered upvoted solutions are just less effective versions of my algorithm.

Comment: is this basically suggesting to look at the binary representation of a IEEE 754 floating-point number? That is, to list off which bits of the mantissa are set, and adjust for the exponent?

Comment: Li-aung Yip@ yes, this way, you get precise and fast result on one hand, and risk loosing portability on the other hand. The straightforward method answer was already there, so I just wanted to offer alternative

Comment: It should work anywhere that uses IEEE 754 floating point. Portable enough for me!

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase the question, what are the one bits in the binary representation of r (after the binary point)?  N is the 'precision', if you like.

In Cish pseudo-code

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
  if (r>V[i]) {
    print(i);
    r -= V[i];
  }
}
```

You could add an extra test for r == 0 to terminate the loop early.

Note that this gives the least binary number closest to 'r', i.e. the one closer to zero if there are two equally 'right' answers.

If the Nth digit was a one, you'll need to add '1' to the 'binary' number obtained and check both against the original 'r'. (Hint: construct vectors a[N], b[N] of 'bits', set '1' bits instead of 'print'ing above.  Set b = a and do a manual add, digit by digit from the end of 'b' until you stop carrying.  Convert to double and choose whichever is closer.

Note that a[] <= r <= a[] + 1/2^N and that b[] = a[] + 1/2^N.

The 'least number of indexes [sic]' is a red-herring.

Comment: There will be scenarios, where the sum will be larger than r, yet the difference will be the smallest of all other possible sums for a given N number of power of 2 reciprocals. hence your solution is invalid.